# "Item not found" when removing a file "prn.html"

Tags: windows, file-management

While cleaning an old Firefox profile, I stumbled upon the "Item not found" error with one of the files, `prn.html`:

[image]

Rebooting, running a disk check and trying to remove the file with elevated privileges didn't help. How to get rid of this file?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, `prn` is still considered a special name in Windows (that's what the printer used to be called 20 years ago), and regular files cannot be accessed by that name. The solution is to remove it from command prompt using wildcards:

```
del *prn.html
```

This works with other "invalid" names as well, such as `con` or a filename ending with a dot.